# Can the rust compiler optimize Array2 better when the shape (size) is known at compile time?

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array, compiler-optimization, compile-time, rust-ndarray

I'm using `Array2` or `Array1` in rust for matrices in a neural network. (Yes, I know there are libraries for NNs. I want to do it with my own code for learning. The question stands independently of the neural networks, but neural networks serve as a suitable example, because here in many cases, the matrix sizes are known at compile time.)

Can the compiler do better optimizations when it knows the size of the `Array2` matrices or `Array1` vectors at compile time? How to make sure it knows them?

Here is code of my neural network layer with lines marked where I think that maybe we can give extra information to the compiler. Or is it not even required in the struct?

```
extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray_rand::RandomExt;
use rand::distributions::Uniform;

struct LayerWithBias<const input_size: usize, const output_size: usize> {
    /// weights
    w: Array2<f32>, // do something with input_size and output_size here?

    /// biases
    b: Array1<f32>, // and do something with just output_size here?
}

impl<const input_size: usize, const output_size: usize>
LayerWithBias<input_size, output_size> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let w = Array2::random((output_size, input_size), Uniform::new(-1.0, 1.0));
        let b = Array1::zeros(output_size);

        LayerWithBias { w, b }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't any specific optimisations that you can enable by telling the compiler the number of items that your `ndarray` collections will eventually hold.

The only way the compiler could *possibly* take advantage of that sort of information would be for fixed-sized arrays, which `ndarray`'s `Array1` and `Array2` are not. Even then, the kinds of optimisations that it could do would be for small arrays, for example to ensure that they fill cache lines efficiently. But if you have a sufficiently large amount of data that it's worth using `ndarray` then this isn't going to make a difference; your data is contiguous and will fill *many* cache lines optimally.

Comment: The first optimization that came to mind is that if the size is known to be a multiple of 16 or 32 bytes (4 or 8 float elements), auto-vectorization doesn't need any cleanup code to handle the odd few elements left-over after doing some number of SIMD vectors.  For a C example, compare two functions with compile-time-constant vs. runtime-variable loop counts: https://godbolt.org/z/1E4v7f1zM .  If the run-time size does turn out to be a multiple of the vector width (times unroll factor), though, the saving is just one extra cmp/branch outside the inner loop, and some dead code.

Comment: Yes exactly. That's what I meant when I said it's not going to make a difference for a large amount of data.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the hints. My matrices and vectors are indeed rather short. I'm currently experimenting with 32 to 128 elements of f32 per NN's vector. All weights together will likely be less than 128KB. I might change later to even less elements and shorter data types near the output layer. So some of the NN's vectors might fit into a single SIMD register. My NNs' output vectors sizes will be powers of 2. If that matters: I'm concerned about inference times, so mat-mat-multiplications don't matter to me, only mat-vec-multiplications.

Comment: Regarding "the compiler could possibly take advantage of that sort of information would be for fixed-sized arrays, which ndarray's Array1 and Array2 are not" - Should I consider alternatives besides `Array1` / `Array2`, e.g. rust arrays like [f32; 32]? Given that I don't care much about mat-mat-mul performance, this sounds like a good alternative to me.